# Using DropDownList as paging function in ASP.Net Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu, formview

I have a Formview that gets populated with SQL data when a dropdown is selected, but when I click edit, it wants to edit the first item on the dropdown list, because technically it still thinks its on the first page. I want the paging to be linked to the drop down but I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this. I have a many fields so I won't post the full Formview but here's the key parts.

Formview Item Template:

```
<ItemTemplate>
          <table id="FormTable">
          <tr><th>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectNameDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataValueField="Project_Name" name="Text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ProjectSelect" AppendDataBoundItems="true">              
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Project" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">             
          </th>
          <th>
            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />                 
          </th></tr>            
           <tr><th>                
            Business Category:
          </th><td>
            <asp:Label ID="BusinessCategoryLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Business_Category") %>'
                 />
            </td></tr>
          <tr><th>
            Project Description:
          </th><td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ProjectDescriptionLabel" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"
                Text='<%# Bind("Project_Description") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" />
            </td></tr>
          <tr><th>
            Operations Owner:
          </th><td>
            <asp:Label ID="OwnerLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("Operations_Owner") %>' />
            </td></tr>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ProjectSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ProjectNameDropDown = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("ProjectNameDropDown");
        Panel Panel1 = (Panel)FormView1.FindControl("Panel1");
        Label BusinessCategoryLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("BusinessCategoryLabel");
        TextBox ProjectDescriptionLabel = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ProjectDescriptionLabel");
        Label OwnerLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("OwnerLabel");
        Label StakeholderLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("StakeholderLabel");
        Label ReqOrgLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("ReqOrgLabel");
        Label PriorityLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("PriorityLabel");
        Label DateInitiatedLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("DateInitiatedLabel");
        Label ReqCompletionDateLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("ReqCompletionDateLabel");
        Label ProjectLOELabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("ProjectLOELabel");
        Label OELabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("OELabel");
        Label PELabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("PELabel");
        Label EMLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("EMLabel");
        Label PARCHLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("PARCHLabel");
        Label WindowsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("WindowsLabel");
        Label StorageLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("StorageLabel");
        Label NetworkLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("NetworkLabel");
        Label Unix2Label = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("Unix2Label");
        Label TSGLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("TSGLabel");
        Label SANDLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("SANDLabel");
        Label MOPSLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("MOPSLabel");
        Label ACSROpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("ACSROpsLabel");
        Label IMOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("IMOpsLabel");
        Label OSCOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("OSCOpsLabel");
        Label FinancialSvcsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("FinancialSvcsLabel");
        Label VantageLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("VantageLabel");
        Label VoiceSysOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("VoiceSysOpsLabel");
        Label VoiceAppOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("VoiceAppOpsLabel");
        Label ACPxOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("ACPxOpsLabel");
        Label WFXOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("WFXOpsLabel");
        Label WebOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("WebOpsLabel");
        Label DBALabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("DBALabel");
        Label CapacityPlanningLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("CapacityPlanningLabel");
        Label BCPLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("BCPLabel");
        Label DataCenterLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("DataCenterLabel");
        Label GoldsmithLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("GoldsmithLabel");
        Label AmericasITOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("AmericasITOpsLabel");
        Label APACITOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("APACITOpsLabel");
        Label EMEAITOpsLabel = (Label)FormView1.FindControl("EMEAITOpsLabel");

        Panel1.Visible = true;
        if (ProjectNameDropDown.Items.FindByText("Select a Project").Selected != true)
        {




            string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=odcsgwinsql11.devcsg.com\ss2008;Initial Catalog=hulc01;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            string MySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Common WHERE Project_Name = '" + ProjectNameDropDown.SelectedValue + "'";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MySelectQuery))
            {
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                myConnection.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter Adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                Adapter1.Fill(dset);
                BusinessCategoryLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Business_Category"].ToString();
                ProjectDescriptionLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Project_Description"].ToString();
                OwnerLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Operations_Owner"].ToString();
                StakeholderLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NonOps_Key_Stakeholder"].ToString();
                ReqOrgLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Requesting_Organization"].ToString();
                PriorityLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Priority"].ToString();
                DateInitiatedLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date_Initiated"].ToString();
                ReqCompletionDateLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Required_Completion_Date"].ToString();
                ProjectLOELabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Project_LOE"].ToString();
                OELabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OE"].ToString();
                PELabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PE"].ToString();
                EMLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EM"].ToString();
                PARCHLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PARCH"].ToString();
                WindowsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Windows"].ToString();
                StorageLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Storage"].ToString();
                NetworkLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Network"].ToString();
                Unix2Label.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UNIX2"].ToString();
                TSGLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TSG"].ToString();
                SANDLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SAND"].ToString();
                MOPSLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MOPS"].ToString();
                ACSROpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACSR_Ops"].ToString();
                IMOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IM_Ops"].ToString();
                OSCOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OSC_Ops"].ToString();
                FinancialSvcsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Financial_Svcs"].ToString();
                VantageLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Vantage"].ToString();
                VoiceAppOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Voice_Sys_Ops"].ToString();
                VoiceSysOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Voice_App_Ops"].ToString();
                ACPxOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACPX_Ops"].ToString();
                WFXOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WFX_Ops"].ToString();
                WebOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Web_Ops"].ToString();
                DBALabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DBA"].ToString();
                CapacityPlanningLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Capacity_Planning"].ToString();
                BCPLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BCP"].ToString();
                DataCenterLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data_Center"].ToString();
                GoldsmithLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Goldsmith"].ToString();
                AmericasITOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Americas_IT_Ops"].ToString();
                APACITOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["APAC_IT_Ops"].ToString();
                EMEAITOpsLabel.Text = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMEA_IT_Ops"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

I imagine somehow telling the Formview what page to switch to when selecting from the dropdown but I haven't been able to figure out the coding for that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, which other options would you have to tell the original poster than as a comment here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (the way I've done it in the past) would be to move your databound `DropDownList` outside of the `FormView`.  Then, bind your `FormView` to a different `SQLDataSource` that's dependent on the `DropDownList`s SelectedValue.  So you would have a DDL with all your Project Names:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Project_Name" 
    DataValueField="Project_Name">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Your Connection String" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Project_Name] FROM [ProjectTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

AND a `FormView` that is dependent upon what is selected in the DDL:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    DataKeyNames="Project_Name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
...
</asp:FormView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Your Connection String" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProjectTable] WHERE Project_Name=@Project_Name">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Project_Name" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This way, when you click the "Edit" button in your `FormView`, you are editing the record you intended to edit.

As a side-note, your Code Behind leaves you very vulnerable to SQL Injection.  I'd be careful about that.  Instead of using string concatenation to generate that SELECT query, you should use Parameterized queries

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't even need the code behind to populate the fields. Thanks again for your help! I was planning on making MIS fix all my security flaws anyways... =)